# Is it possible to return the results of a select statement with an IN clause?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
select ('hi' in ('hi')) as hi
```

It's not working due to bad syntax at the "in" portion.

Is it possible to return the boolean result of a subquery with an IN clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a CASE, e.g.

```
select 
  case 
     when 'hi' in ('hi') then 1 else 0 
 end as hi
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a conditional expression using `CASE`:

```
select
    case when 'hi' in ('hi') then 1 else 0 end
```

[Here is a demo on sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16579).

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you can do is return the condition value as a bit using a case statement as such:

```
select case when 'hi' in ('hi') then 1 else 0 end as hi
```